# asp.net MVC JavaScript call to controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net MVC project.
I have a JavaScript function which takes an XML string as input.  I would like to send this to the controller.

I have done so using an AJAX request, but in the controller the string is null.

View:

```
        function save() {
            var xml = scheduler.toXML();
            alert(xml);

            var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")'

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                Type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                data: xml,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) { alert("OK");},
                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert('Error message.');
            }
            });
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Save(string xml)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xml);

        W6ViewModel viewModel = new W6ViewModel();
        viewModel.engineers = db.W6ENGINEERS.ToList();
        viewModel.tasks = db.W6TASKS.ToList();
        viewModel.skills = db.W6TASKS_REQUIRED_SKILLS1.ToList();

        var engList = new List<object>();
        foreach (var engineer in viewModel.engineers)
        {
            engList.Add(new { key = engineer.ID, label = engineer.Name });
        }
        ViewBag.engineers = engList;

        return View("Index", viewModel);
    }

var xml = scheduler.toXML()
```

alert(xml):

[image]

Error Code (Sorry, wall of text):

```
[HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (xmlString=&quot;&lt;data&gt;&lt;event&gt;
```

Comment: everything seems to be `XML`, but the `contenttype` is `json` ?

Comment: yes your right, but the scheduler.toXML() returns a sting I believe.http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/api__scheduler_toxml.html

Comment: there is also a `dataType: "xml"` which should set the contentType for you

Comment: I get an error when i change the dataType to XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name your parameter like this:

```
function save() {
        var xml = scheduler.toXML();
        alert(xml);

        var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            Type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data: { xml: xml},
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) { alert("OK");},
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            alert('Error message.');
        }
        });
```

Also put this tag above you controller action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when i do this, the error message kicks in, not sure why.

Comment: soory, but im not to sure what the error is, it just says error even after writing:

                error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(exception);
            }

Comment: Check second part of my answer

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using Ajax?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

See the following `ajax` call:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/myaccount/CheckDuplicateEmailAddress")',
            data: { "emailAddress": email },
            async: false,
            type: "post",
            success: success,
            error: error
        });
```

And controller action is below. you need to send param as this:

```
data: { "emailAddress": email }
```

Remember case sensitivity and double quotes:

```
public bool CheckDuplicateEmailAddress(string emailAddress)
    {
    }
```

Comment: Tried this, i got an the same error as the answer mentioned above!

Comment: what does this alert gives.                                                              var xml = scheduler.toXML();
 alert(xml);

Comment: It is just an alert saying "error"

if there is a way to get the error, may you show me please?

Comment: when i do that, it is not null, but ill post it in a sec

Comment: yes you need to install a tool similar to firebug as in Mozilla. there you can see all javascript errors.

Comment: try setting your string a hardcode value . var xml ="stephen" & see if it is passed to controller. I guess there is problem in string that you are sending as it may contain any escape character

Comment: Will try this, didn't know why I didn't think of it!

Comment: So upon changing the value of xml to "Stephen", it works no problem!

Comment: you can use this                                                         [Post, ValidateInput(false)]
public bool CheckDuplicateEmailAddress(string emailAddress) {
   //your code
}                                                                                           this might help. try this. but it is not recommended

Comment: I tried this, got an error: "The Resource cannot be found"

Comment: once again try hard coding string . in this scenario to check if problem is still with string that you are sending or you are missing any attribute on your action

Comment: I found the answer!
i had to put ValidateInput(false), without the Post though.